# One very strange os.getcwd - Yes the directory exists

Tags: python-3.4

Let me just jump straight in because I'm feeling kind of strange at the moment.

```
mkdir /var/tmp/myuser
cd /var/tmp/myuser
python
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno2] No such file or directory
>>> exit()
pwd
/var/tmp/myuser
```

There's no magic the directory is there, I have full access. How should I troubleshoot an issue like this?

Comment: `strace python -c "import os; os.getcwd()"`? (on Unixen at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try executing os.chdir(path to your current directory) and then os.getcwd()?

Comment: Interesting... I don't know why it works but it works. If something looks stupid but it works it ain't stupid. I'm just gonna leave it there.